# Confustion on core data for storing multiple records

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I am newbie in core data, and my problem is to store multiple records in core data.
I have two tables first is "Products" which has just product info and second one is "Brand" which has brand info plus this have to have multiple records, so for recording multiples products I am getting confuse on how to have multiples products in Brands.
There are two solution plus with some confusion in my mind which I want to clear from some expert guys or who worked on it.

- If I create relationship with 1 to many of brands with products table, then when I'll create `NSManagedObject` class for Brands, its will has NSSet class with products. My confusion is that will I be able to use this as array or as multiples records of products.
- I will add attribute of products with Binary Data and then convert this into NSData then into NSArray. My confusion is at this solution is that, Do I need to have relation Brands with products still after adding attribute of products or this will be fine If I'll don't have and if this fine then what is use of relation.

Kindly explain me any one expert, I am confuse over here, and looking for healthy response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use relationships. Be sure each has an inverse.

Comment: Thanks, Wain, I am using inverse relationship, but do I get all information by using just nsset form, or then I'll still need to add an extra attribute type or array or binary data? If first answer is right that I'll get all info then How to fetch data from nsset?

Comment: Do you want to filter based on some attribute? Or you want all items in an order (how will they be sorted)? I'm really not that clear from your explanation, sorry.

Comment: @Wain I want to fetch all elements in products table?

Comment: So just use a fetch request (preferably with a batch size set)...

Comment: @Wain Thanks, We'll do exactly what you suggest, finger cross :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be if you go with relationshipas that way u would be able to get back n forth for information. Also NSSet class would help you to code down your info into core data easy way. Also relationship would help to filter out stuff if you would require search feature or any other future implementation. Anything else let me know.

Comment: Thanks walle, so do you think that I'll get all info of product in nsset form, and I don't really need to add extra attribute for products as array or binary data? Also how do I fetch that data from nsset form?

Comment: No need for array as you are already using relationship of 1-many which will provide you 1 brand with multiple products so you would be able to fetch all products related to one brand. Also u need to surf through your topic as no spoon feeding will be done. Moreover your using relationship so you shouldn't be using NSSet but still its upto what your app requires as scope. Also I have no idea of wt all details and feature you would provide. So NSSet is kinda no for me with this much info you provide.